# System Exception: 'Cannot create a table without columns, does it have public properties?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I am creating a Xamarin form where I have to create a table to save details (user and password).

When I run this on emulator I end up with this error:

> System Exception: cannot create table without columns

In VIEWS:

```
private async void _saveButton_Clicked(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);

    db.CreateTable<User>();

    var maxPk = db.Table<User>().OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    User user = new User()
        {
            Id = (maxPk == null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(maxPk.Id) +1),
            Email = _emailEntry.Text,
            Password = _passwordEntry.Text
        };

    db.Insert(user);
    await DisplayAlert(null, "Saved", "Ok");
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

In MODELS:

```
using SQLite;

namespace LoginPage.Models
{
    public class LoginPage
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Email + "," + this.Password;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purposes of calling db.CreateTable every time you save a new user?

Comment: _db.CreateTable()_ as far as I know is spezial to _SqlLite_. It should create or open the table. But back to the original question - the model is incomplete, we only see properties. Is the class public?

Comment: yes class is public. edited the post too

Comment: `CreateTable<User>` but your model/class is `LoginPage`?

Comment: Can you share a demo with your issue?

Answer (score 3):

In Models change the name of your class to User. That is the Table Model you are trying to create.

using SQLite;

```
namespace LoginPage.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Email + "," + this.Password;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: modified as such, now i get the same error: **System.Exception:** 'Cannot create a table without columns (does 'LoginPage.Views.User' have public properties?)'

Comment: You have the Wrong NameSpace: It should be LoginPage.Models.User

Comment: no that doe nots help too, I still get the same error